# How to run JavaScript inside electron?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an electron app which takes code entered into a text area, runs it and returns the result. How to convert the text to JavaScript and run it.

Comment: hmm.. why would you want to run arbitrary JS code supplied by user? If its absolutely necessary, use eval

Comment: Why not? i mean, maybe that's the whole purpose of the app.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function to run text from an input field:

```js
document.getElementById("2").onchange = () => {
  document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("2").value.toString())
}
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<input id="2">
```

Note that this is not safe at all and you should never use this in production unless heavily safeguarded. [See this!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

Comment: Why are you downvoting without explanation?